# Uninterpretable Eclipse Error when installing m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

When trying to install the current version of m2eclipse (0.12.1.20110112-1712) I get an error which doesn't really help me:

```
  Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.4.100.v20090429-1800 (org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.4.100.v20090429-1800)
    Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.5.0.v20100515 (org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.5.0.v20100515)
    Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.5.1.R36x_v20100824 (org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.5.1.R36x_v20100824)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
    To: org.eclipse.core.jobs [3.4.100.v20090429-1800]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Model 1.1.500.v201006020308 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 1.1.500.v201006020308)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs [3.5.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Model 1.1.502.v201008311901 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 1.1.502.v201008311901)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs [3.5.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0
```

My Eclipse version is 3.5.2 and I'm using it under Ubuntu. Maybe someone has an idea? Googling did only bring up error messages at the Eclipse marketplace without any discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), which is not officially supported by Ubuntu 10.04. Now, m2eclipse could be installed without a problem.

This is not the most optimal solution, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about Helios being unsupported on Ubuntu according to presumably Ubuntu. Helios is well supported on pretty much all flavors of Linux by the Eclipse community.

If you do want to try installing m2eclipse into your existing Eclipse 3.5 "Galileo" installation, try unchecking the checkbox that reads something like "consult all available update sites" on the screen where you enter m2eclipse update site URL.

Comment: thanks for your hint, but I think I will just use Helios now :)